# Protect backups that are generating automatically by shell script

Tags: bash, shell, security, encryption, password-protection

I have a database set in **serverA**. There is another **serverB** for storing backups.

A shell script on **serverA** every 6 hours generates a backup of database and compress it to tar.gz format and send it to **serverB** throw SSH SCP.

I need to protect backup tar.gz files by password or a secure way before sending to **serverB**.

There are many ways to set password on tar.gz file but all off them need to do that on ssh by human and entering the password. But I need do it by shell script automatically.

I`m looking for a protection way that I could set a secret key on that. Maybe password protection maybe encryption by key that I can decrypt it in feature by that key.

Comment: Have you tried using [this answer for gpg](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68726/187122) or [this answer for openssl](https://superuser.com/a/724987/652023)?

Comment: What is the OS on the servers?

Comment: OS of my server is Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Look for `PGP`: Something like `tar -c ... | gzip | gpg -aer authoritedUser | ssh target dd of=target_file.tgz.gpg`